# Returning multiple values in datatables from the same column

Tags: jquery, datatable

```
$('#nom_freq').change(function() {
    table.column( $(this).data('column') )
        .search(( $(this).val() )* 2)
        .draw();
        
})
```

Lets say i have a value of 10, so 10*2 = 20, how could i display the value from 16 to 25?
Like displaying a range of ten from the value i get, sorry for the grammar and i'm a beginner.

Comment: First of all, hello and welcome to SO! Are you trying to edit a single cell or an entire column?

Comment: Entire column sir. its like the range of value where the computed value is in the middle.